# No Module name "Speech recognition"

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

I have Installed SpeechRecognition by pip

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

and by conda ( because I have used virenv under conda)

```
conda install -c conda-forge speechrecognition
```

this is part of my code it is a bot to solve captcha

```
#system libraries
import os
import random
import time
#selenium libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException   
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import 
UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#recaptcha libraries
import speech_recognition as sr
sr.__version__

import ffmpy
import requests
import urllib
import pydub

#access to google recaptcha demo 
DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/formation/python/recaptcha_Bot/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
```

but always when I run code It shows error (`not module name "speech-recognition"`
What I am trying to look :
`python/Lib/site-packages/` and in `anaconda3/Lib/site-packages`
I don't find SpeechRecognition package but when I run pip list I found the package installed

Comment: clearly you are not running your code with the same python which has installed `speech_recognition`.  Your mre can be a lot smaller btw: just running [`python -m speech_recognition`](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#readme) is enough per the docs to see if things run or not; or a file with `import speech_recognition`.  In any case: how do you run your code?

Comment: as a quick try, run `PYTHON -m pip install SpeechRecognition` where `PYTHON` is whatever you use to run your code (probably a matter of activating the conda env and using its python).

Comment: yes I am already activeted the conda env and its python (3.9) then I install speechrecognition

Comment: *how* did you install?  with `pip install`?  In that case try explicitly invoking the correct python interpreter `/correct/python -m pip install`.  And how are you running the test?

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too (IDK why).

First I installed a module names pipwin using

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then I used--

```
pipwin install SpeechRecognition
```

Comment: pipwin is basically a wrapper around pip, according to the docs, with nicer downloading and searching.  If it fixed the problem it would be via detecting or being invoked by the *correct* python, and hence installing into the correct venv; it's probably orthoganal to the real problem here.

Comment: I try with pipwin but not working